# Find all the functions $f(x)$ where $f(x\sqrt{2}) = 2f(x)$ and $f(x+1) = f(x)+2x +1$ for all real $x$.

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Find all the functions $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x\sqrt{2}) = 2f(x)$$ and $$f(x+1) = f(x)+2x +1$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

So, the only function that I intuitively can imaging is $f(x) = x^{2}$, but I tried to plug $x=0$ and other different expressions and numbers without any success. Is there any other functions and how to prove that $f(x)=x^{2}$. Could you give me any hint?

Comment: The value of $ f $ at $ x $ is only related to the value of $ f $ at countably many other points. Precisely, consider the equivalence relation generated by the set of pairs of the form $ ( x , x + 1 ) $ and $ \left ( x , \sqrt 2 x \right ) $. Pick a representative for any equivalence class and choose the value of $ f $ for it arbitrarily. Then the value of $ f $ at any point will be uniquely determined. Without further assumptions of $ f $, that's about the best characterization of the solutions you can hope for.

Comment: I hope, there exist a solution that 8th grade student can understand it.

Comment: I'm afraid, there is not, as far as I can tell. There are uncountably many solutions, and almost all of them look very ugly, and therefore can't be described much better than what I tried to present.

Comment: But shouldn't it be noted that it is clear $f(x) = x^{2}$ clearly satisfies both requirements, as part of OP's question.

Comment: Bad for me. However the question was located on level 2 (which means not so hard, even for beginners) of math contest questions.

Comment: But I think it is not sufficient to say that we found all functions.

Comment: @DerekLuna That's true. And the silverlining is that $ f ( x ) = x ^ 2 $ is the only *continuous* solution. For seeing that, one can define $ g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ with $ g ( x ) = f ( x ) - x ^ 2 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. Then the equations become $ g \left ( \sqrt 2 x \right ) = 2 g ( x ) $ and $ g ( x + 1 ) = g ( x ) $. From the first equation we get $ g \left ( \frac x { \sqrt 2 } \right ) = \frac { f ( x ) } 2 $. By induction we get $ g \left ( \frac x { \sqrt 2 ^ n } \right ) = \frac { f ( x ) } { 2 ^ n } $ for any positive integer $ n $. *(to be continued)*

Comment: *(continued)* $ g $ is also continuous, and taking the limit as $ n \to \infty $ one gets $ g ( 0 ) = 0 $. From the second equation and induction, one gets $ g ( n ) = 0 $ for any integer $ n $. The first equation together with induction then shows $ g \left ( \frac n { 2 ^ m } \right ) = 0 $ for all integers $ n $ and $ m $. As numbers of the form $ \frac n { 2 ^ m } $ are dense in the real line and $ g $ is continuous, one gets $ g ( x ) = 0 $, or equivalently $ f ( x ) = x ^ 2 $, for all $ x \in \mathbb R $.

Comment: What @MohsenShahriari is saying is that there is not a nice way to describe **all** possible functions ${f(x)}$ because from the information given, using some initial condition can only describe what values ${f(x)}$ should take on at countably many points, but ${\mathbb{R}}$ is uncountable

Comment: I just realized that the part for deriving $ g ( 0 ) = 0 $ was too complicated. One just needs to put $ x = 0 $ in $ g \left ( \sqrt 2 x \right ) = 2 g ( x ) $, and get $ g ( 0 ) = 0 $. The reasoning is needed for the part about $ g \left ( \frac n { 2 ^ m } \right ) = 0 $ though, as is mentioned.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari A possible way to characterize the equivalence relation is that $x\sim  y$ if and only if $\sqrt 2^k (x-m) = y-n$ for some $k, m, n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari Your first comment isn't true. Specifically, "Pick a representative for any equivalence class and choose the value of $f$ for it arbitrarily." As an example, suppose we pick $ f(0) = 1$. Then this gives $f(1) = 1+0+1 = 2, f(2) = 2+2+1 = 5,$ (seemingly giving us $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ which is to be expected). However, we also have $ f( \sqrt{2} ) = 2 f(1) = 4, f(2) = 2f(\sqrt{2} ) = 8 $, hence a contradiction. $\quad$

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks. I was actually aware of that. I just wanted to avoid making it more complicated. The correct version would be "any equivalence class other that of $ 0 $", and as Diger's answer demonstrates, on that special class we must actually have $ f ( x ) = x ^ 2 $.

Comment: @SungjinKim Shouldn't that be $ x \sim y $ iff $ \sqrt 2 ^ k ( x - m ) = y - n \sqrt 2 ^ j $ for some $ j , k , m , n \in \mathbb Z $, or something?

Comment: @MohsenShahriari Yes, you are right. Mine was over-simplified.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari For $g(x)=f(x)-x^2$, we have $g(x+1)=g(x)$ and $g(x\sqrt 2)=2g(x)$. So, the function values of $g$ cannot be just given on the equivalence class. We should have a suitable modification to satisfy $g(x\sqrt 2)=2g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $$f(x)=x^2+g(x)$$ and plug it into the equations. You will obtain $$g(x+1)=g(x) \tag{1}$$ $$g(\sqrt{2}x)=2g(x) \tag{2}$$
i.e. $g$ is periodic with period $1$. Now:

- From the second equation you get $g(0)=0$ and by the periodicity $g(n)=0$ at all integers.
- Furthermore $g(\sqrt{2})=0$ and so $g(\sqrt{2}+1)=0$. Inductively $g(m\sqrt{2}+n)=0$ for integers $m,n$.
- Similarly you can set $x=m/\sqrt{2}$ in equation (2) to find $g(m/\sqrt{2})=0$. Repeating this process will give $g(m/2^{k/2})=0$.
- You can repeatedly apply (1) and (2) to first find $g(m2^{k/2}+n2^{l/2})=0$ for $m,k,n,l\in \mathbb{Z}$ or more generally $$g\left(\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} m_k 2^k + \sqrt{2} \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} n_k 2^k\right)=0 \, .$$
- The last result implies (binary representation) $$g(x\sqrt{2}+y)=0$$ for $x,y$ being dyadic rationals.

Comment: The last claim is not true. You only get $ g \left ( x \sqrt 2 + y \right ) = 0 $ for [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) $ x $ and $ y $, from the previous step.

Comment: Yeah true. Thanks for pointing out. I'm wondering if this iteration process is allowed ad infinitum to get reals and if not why?

Comment: What you're seeking is possible under the assumption that $ g $ is continuous, as dyadic rationals are dense in the real line. As for why it's not possible without further assumptions on $ g $, consider the equivalence relation in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4292899/find-all-the-functions-fx-where-fx-sqrt2-2fx-and-fx1-fx2x#comment8939095_4292899) above. Then you can deal with the value of $ f $ on each equivalence class separately, and come up with many many different solutions, in particular those such that only take the value zero at the points mentioned by you.

Comment: I see. That pretty much boils down to the definition of continuity if you write equation (2) as $$g(x)=\frac{g(2^{k/2}x)}{2^k} \, .$$ If $x$ has a finite dyadic expansion with lsb=$2^{-n}$, then you can choose $k=2n$ s.t the RHS is zero, because the argument is an integer. Otherwise, if $x$ has only an infinite dyadic expansion, then consider the sequence of approximations $x_n$ with lsb=$2^{-n}$ s.t. the RHS is again zero and so $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} g(x_n)=0$$ and interchanging the limit is allowed only if $g$ is continuous.